# How to use allocatable arrays in Fortran subroutines?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, subroutine

Let me just preface this by saying that I am very new to Fortran but familiar with Python. My research project however requires me to use some pre-written Fortran code, which at this moment wont compile on my pc. I am trying to understand why.

The actual code I am trying to compile is very long and probably not very illuminating, but I think I have managed to come up with a minimal example of where I think the issue is. Let's say I have a very simple module and subroutine as follows,

```
module arraycheck
    implicit none
    real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: x
    contains
    subroutine fillx
        real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: x
        allocate(x(5))
        x(1) = 1
        x(2) = 2
        x(3) = 3
        x(4) = 4
        x(5) = 5
        print*, x
    end subroutine fillx
end module arraycheck
```

which I expect to simply create an array `x`, which when the subroutine `fillx` is called fills the array with the integers 1 to 5. My actual source contains something conceptually similar to this. Now I also have a `main` program as follows,

```
program main
use arraycheck
print*, x
call fillx
print*,x
end
```

My idea here would be that on the first `print` statement the variable `x` is still unallocated, so `print` returns nothing, and then on the second `print` statement `x` has been filled, so it should return the filled array.

However on both `print` statements nothing is returned. Now in my original source code something similar happens, which causes runtime to throw an error that an unallocated array was passed somewhere as an actual argument, which should have been allocated. It seems like the exact same thing happens as in my small example here.

So my question is, is the behaviour that I observe in my example here expected? And if it is, how can I alter the code to make it work in the way that I would want it to? If I know this I might better understand why the actual source doesn't work.

Just in case it is relevant, I am using gfortran on ubuntu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too different `x`s. They do not have anything in common. One a module array and one array local to the subroutine. When you allocate the local array in the subroutine, it does not do anything to the other array in the module.

Also, you cannot print array that is not allocated. That is not standard conforming (undefined behaviour). Anything can happen. You should definitely enable all compiler checks when diagnosing problems. The compiler should complain about your code with those checks.

Remove the local array declaration and avoid referencing unallocated variables. Module procedures have access to module  variables through host association.

```
module arraycheck
    implicit none
    real*8, allocatable, dimension(:) :: x

  contains

    subroutine fillx

        allocate(x(5))
        x(1) = 1
        x(2) = 2
        x(3) = 3
        x(4) = 4
        x(5) = 5
        print*, x
    end subroutine fillx
end module arraycheck


program main
  use arraycheck

  call fillx
  print*,x
end
```

Also, `real*8` is not standard Fortran, it is a non-standard extension. Fortran 90 and later uses the kind system instead.

Comment: Yeah I see now, this makes much more sense indeed, guess I'll have to edit that source code somewhat, but at least now I know where the problem is. The real*8 extension was just something present in the source, maybe I can update that as well if its non standard.

Comment: I showed the real*8 in an answer for you, and IMPLICIT NONE, and RETURN.

Comment: Will this still work if fillx call a subroutine in a different module that also uses x?

Comment: @SimonWoodward Impossible to say without further details. In general yes, but it really depends on the exact code.

Answer (score -2):

Here are some other things which might be helpful - shown in UPPERCASE.

```
module arraycheck
    USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_Int32_t, C_DOUBLE
    implicit none
    PRIVATE

    real(KIND=C_DOUBLE), allocatable, dimension(:), PUBLIC :: x

    PUBLIC Creation_X, Destruction_X, FillX

  contains

    subroutine Creation_X(n)
    USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_Int32_t
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(KIND=C_Int32_t), INTENT(IN) :: n

    allocate(x(n))

    RETURN
    end subroutine Creation_X

    subroutine Destruction_X
    USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_Int32_t
    IMPLICIT NONE

    IF(ALLOCATED(X)) DEALLOCATE(X)

    RETURN
    end subroutine Destruction_X

    subroutine fillx
    USE ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY : C_Int32_t
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER(KIND=C_Int32_t) :: N

    DO I= 1, SIZE(x)
      x(I) = I
    ENDDO

    RETURN
    end subroutine fillx

end module arraycheck


program main
  use arraycheck

  CALL Creation_X(5)
  call fillx
  print*,x
  CALL Destruction_X

end
```